# Check whether any checkbox being selected in a nested component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, nested

I need to add validation on a page what if none of the checkbox questions being selected, error msg shows. However, this checkbox is kind of inside a nested component called "question".

The page to call "question" component is **questionnaire-detail.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let applicant of applicants$ | async">
<div *ngIf="applicant.id === (applicant$ | async)?.id">
<app-question [applicants]="applicants$ | async" [currentApplicantId]="applicant.id" [parentForm]="form" *ngFor="let question of questionnaire$ | async"
  [question]="question" [submitted]="submitted" [minLevel]="3" [initialResponses]="initialResponses$ | async"
  [applicantIndexesById]="applicantIndexesById$ | async"></app-question>
```

And the **question.component.html** has **question** inside itself. We pass a lot of parameters to question component. If it matches the checkbox style, the app-question-checkbox will be called. So inside "let childQuestion of question.questions", each childQuestion could be a checkbox question or other style question.

```
<div *ngIf="!!question?.id && !!currentApplicantId && isChoiceQuestion(parentQuestion) && doesQuestionApplyToCurrentApplicant(question)">
  <app-question-checkbox [formControl]="formControl" text="{{question?.text}}" description="{{question?.description}}"
    [readonlyInput]="readonlyInput"></app-question-checkbox>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!!question && !!question?.questions && doesQuestionApplyToCurrentApplicant(question) && (!question?.id || isCurrentQuestionAnswered())"
[ngClass]="{ 'appform': isChoiceQuestion(question) || !currentApplicantId, 'nested-questions': isChoiceQuestion(question) || (!!parentQuestionId && !!currentApplicantId) }">
<div *ngFor="let childQuestion of question.questions; let i = index">
  <app-question *ngIf="!parentQuestionId || (isChoiceQuestion(question) || shouldDisplayQuestionBasedOnResponse(childQuestion, currentQuestionResponse))"
    [question]="childQuestion" [parentQuestionId]="!question.id? parentQuestionId: question.id"
    [parentQuestionType]="!question.type? parentQuestion?.type: question.type" [parentQuestion]="question"
    [applicants]="applicants" [currentApplicantId]="currentApplicantId" [parentForm]="parentForm"
    [parentQuestionResponse]="!currentQuestionResponse ? parentQuestionResponse : currentQuestionResponse"
    [submitted]="submitted" [level]="level" [minLevel]="minLevel" [maxLevel]="maxLevel" [initialResponses]="initialResponses"
    (selected)="onQuestionSelected($event)" [expanded]="currentlySelectedQuestionId === childQuestion.id"
    [applicantIndexesById]="applicantIndexesById" [readonlyInput]="readonlyInput" [productsSelected]="productsSelected"
    [showNoneOfTheAboveForChoiceQuestions]="showNoneOfTheAboveForChoiceQuestions" (responseChanged)="onResponseChanged($event)">
  </app-question>
</div>
```

The thing is I can't put validation on question component since it's shared by other systems and other systems don't need the validation. So I have to add validation on **questionnaire-detail** component.

Is there any way to check whether any of the checkboxs being selected from the parent component **questionnaire-detail**?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved our problem by adding a validator component inside the question component.

**question.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="shouldValidateAtLeastOneCheckboxChecked()">
  <app-required-checkbox-validator [parentForm]="parentForm" [submitted]="submitted" text="Please select at least one of the above options"></app-required-checkbox-validator>
</div>
```

And in the validator component, use required validation inside constructor. Thus, once the user click submit, it will validate whether any of the checkboxes is selected. If not, it will show error message.

**required-checkbox-validator.component.ts**

```
constructor() {
this.control = new FormControl('', (control: AbstractControl) => ({ required: true }));
```

}

Hope this will help someone who had similar issue with us.

Answer (score 0):

You can import child component in parent component using DI. in your case, expose public method 'validateQuestiocCheckbox' method that will return validation result.
It will be called in parent component.

**questionnaire-detail.component**

```
constructor(private qc: questionComponent){}

ngOnInit(){
  this.qc.validateQuestiocCheckbox();
}
```

**question.Component**

```
validateQuestiocCheckbox(){
   // section of code used to validate question checkbox
   //return true/false
}
```

Comment: Thanks Suresh. I tried but keep getting error like "QuestionnaireDetailComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'isCurrentQuestionAnswered2' of null
    at QuestionnaireDetailComponent.push../questionnaire/questionnaire-detail/questionnaire-detail.component.ts.QuestionnaireDetailComponent.ngOnInit". "isCurrentQuestionAnswered2" is my test version of "validateQuestiocCheckbox" which always return true. Anything I miss here?

Comment: can you create a stackblitz. will take a look at it

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was working on something else. We solved the problem by adding a validator component as I show in my own answer. Thanks for helping me Suresh!